# Why does the rmail-php-class fail if I setText(), but works if I only setHtml()?

Tags: php, email, send

I use this class for sending e-mail: 
http://www.phpguru.org/downloads/Rmail/Rmail%20for%20PHP/docs.html

It was working until I switched from "mail" to SMTP. 
Now, if I use `setHtml($html)` it works, but if I also use `setText($text)`, it doesn't work.

Can it be that `$text` contains some invalid characters?
Why would those characters work when using the system "mail", 
but not work on SMTP running on localhost?

Comment: Things I have tried: 
text lines in $text were too long, I wrapped them at 75 characters, using "\r\n". This same EOL is used for the $html part, which works. 
I replaced a line beginning with "--" with "__".

If I replace $text (long UTF8 string) with the string "SIMPLE", it works. There must be some character it does not like.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out `"\n"` characters (LF) are not allowed, only `"\r\n"` (CRLF) is acceptable in the e-mail text body.

Somehow among all the CRLF pairs one LF sneaked in, which caused the sending to fail.

Aren't bytes wonderful?